# Azure Video Indexer API - Uploading multiple files

Tags: azure-video-indexer

I'm trying to upload multiple videos to the Video Indexer using the API. The first one uploads without issue, but the next one(s) keep giving me the following error:

StatusCode: 409, ReasonPhrase: 'Conflict'

I've verified that the name and enternalID parameters are unique for each video.

If I insert a breakpoint and wait until the first one is finished indexing, the next one will upload and index without issue.